# Problema con clases css al generar tabla dinámica con jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un CRUD con ajax y a la hora de mostrar los resultados de una consulta genero una tabla con dichos resultados recibidos a través de json desde php, el problema es que al generar la tabla, al final de cada fila coloco dos botones uno para llamar a una función javascript para eliminar ese artículo y otro para editarlo. El problemea es que al querer ejecutar la función con el evento click en jquery, este no llama a la función.

**Código para generar la tabla**

```
var registros_sql = JSON.parse(resultados);
var tabla = "";

for(var i in registros_sql){

    tabla += `<tr>
                <th scope='row'>${registros_sql[i].CODIGOARTICULO}</th>
                <td>${registros_sql[i].SECCION}</td>
                <td>${registros_sql[i].NOMBREARTICULO}</td>
                <td>${registros_sql[i].PRECIO}</td>
                <td>${registros_sql[i].PAISDEORIGEN}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class='btn_llamar_editar' style='width: 40px;' data-id='${registros_sql[i].CODIGOARTICULO}'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>
                    <button class='btn_llamar_eliminar' style='width: 40px;' data-id='${registros_sql[i].CODIGOARTICULO}'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>`;
}

$("#insercion").html(tabla);
```

})

**Código para asignarle un evento a los botones**

```
$(".btn_llamar_eliminar").on("click", function(){

    var articulo = $(this).attr("data-id");

    eliminar_productos(articulo);
});
```

**Función eliminar_productos**

```
function eliminar_productos(id_producto){

    alert("El producto a eliminar es: " + id_producto);

}
```

Lo que no entiendo es porque en los botones que se generan dinamicamente no funciona, pero si yo voy directo al html y creo un botón con la clase btn_llamar_eliminar, el evento si se ejecuta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice un ejemplo para mostrar la solución al problema, hice una tabla dinámica y se genera en el div #insercion:

```js
$("button#table").on("click", function() {

var tabla = "<table id='dinamic'>";

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  tabla += "<tr><th scope='row'>HEAD</th><td><button class='btn_llamar_editar' style='width: 40px;' data-id='"+i+"'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button><button class='btn_llamar_eliminar' style='width: 40px;' data-id='"+i+"'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button></td></tr>";
}
tabla += "</table>";
$("#insercion").html(tabla);

});

$("#insercion").on("click",".btn_llamar_editar", function() {
  var articulo = $(this).attr("data-id");
  alert("El producto a editar es: " + articulo);
});

$("#insercion").on("click",".btn_llamar_eliminar", function() {
  var articulo = $(this).attr("data-id");
  eliminar_productos(articulo);
});


function eliminar_productos(id_producto) {

    alert("El producto a eliminar es: " + id_producto);

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="table">crear tabla</button>
<div id='insercion'></div>
```

Cuando añado el evento click, el selector apunta al div #insercion y en el parámetro del click agrego el botón creado dinamicamente en la tabla. De esta manera sí funciona.

> Al utilizar `on()`, los eventos delegados tienen la ventaja de que pueden procesar eventos de elementos descendientes que se agregan al documento en un momento posterior.

Comment: Gracias crack!, la explicación me sirvió a la perfección para entenderlo.